# Update producer config for Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have Kafka installed on ubuntu server with debezium connector very similar to [this](https://sandeepkattepogu.medium.com/streaming-data-from-microsoft-sql-server-into-apache-kafka-2fb53282115f). I am trying to update producer configuration with following

```
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
enable.idempotence=true
acks=all
```

For this I updated `/etc/kafka/config/producer.properties` file. But when I check the connect logs I see Producer config as following:

```
ProducerConfig values:
acks = 1
enable.idempotence = false
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
....
....
```

With a message `Idempotence will be disabled because acks is set to 1, not set to 'all'.`

So I am trying to figure out where can I update this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing actually uses `producer.properties`

To edit Kafka Connect properties, such as Debezium, use the Debezium config itself with `producer.override.`, or `connect-distributed.properties` with just `producer.` prefix.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running